# Pip installing packages in global environment instead of virtualenv on Windows

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am using pycharm and for that i am using python virtualenv.

I activate virtualenv using `penv\Scripts\activate.bat` command. But when i run `pip install requests`, it is getting installed in global folder instead of local virtualenv folder. I am not able to understand why is the case so.

Output of `where python` is as follow:

```
E:\app-backend\penv\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\Hardik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

Output of `where pip` is as follow:

```
E:\app-backend\penv\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Hardik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe
```

I have tried it again and again but it always installs any package in global folder. But when I run any command using `E:\app-backend\penv\Scripts\pip.exe` install of `pip`, it installs that package in local virtualenv.

Can anyone tell me what is the case happening here?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: I have tried that as well. Even that does not work.

Comment: Are you using the terminal window in PyCharm, do you see your virtual env in parenthesis before the prompt like `(venv) homedir/path $` and did you set the virtual environment in your project settings?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but adding this solution for anyone who will face this issue in the future.
In my case the issue source was the fact that I moved the virtual env folder to a different location, so the path in activate was wrong.
Basically for me the fix was:

1. Opening activate.bat (for windows) and correcting the path for VIRTUAL_ENV (for mac would edit activate)
2. After that need to call deactivate and activate again.

This fixed the issue for me. Hope helps someone.

Comment: This is a good answer. The paths need to be changed if the folder has been moved. However, it still doesn't resolve the issue with the latest version of Pycharm (2020.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

You should run python from your virtual enviromment.
For example:

```
E:\app-backend\penv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip list
```

But you should activate your venv first:

```
E:\app-backend\penv\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: OP seems to have activated the environment before asking the doubt.