# Pip package install in both globally and in virtualenv

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

I have a problem with installing my pip packages. I have created a virtualenv and when I try to install packages through pip, it gets install both globally and inside my virtualenv. Does anyone have any solution why this is happening? I want to solution to be for windows.

Comment: I had the same error with no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708993/pip-installing-packages-in-global-environment-instead-of-virtualenv-on-windows

Comment: I shifted to WSL(Windows subsystem for Linux) after all this to get it resolved. WSL works without any problem except that it is a little bit slower. But if you want windows environment only, then I still haven't found any solution.

Comment: @hardik24 i dont wanna switch..well thanx for the suggestion